# Autowired repository NPE Spring Boot apllication junit test

Tags: java, null, spring-data

Есть класс

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.dao;

import dev5.lavishek.trains.entity.Ticket;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends CrudRepository<Ticket, Integer> {

  @Query(value = "SELECT ticket "
      + "FROM Ticket ticket "
      + "WHERE ((ticket.train.id =:idTrain) AND (ticket.dateDeparture=:departure))")
  List<Ticket> getTicketsByTrainAndDate(@Param("idTrain") Integer idTrain,
      @Param("departure") LocalDate dateDeparture);

}
```

Пишу для него тест

```
package dev5.lavishek.trains.dao;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.TestEntityManager;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
class TicketRepositoryTest {

  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager entityManager;
  @Autowired
  private TicketRepository repository;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    repository.findAll();

  }

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() {
  }

  @Test
  void getTicketsByTrainAndDate() {

  }

}
```

Структура проекта [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:C:\\Users\\Alexander\\YandexDisk\\NetCracker\\TrainsProject\\database\\database
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=1234
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

В классе с тестами @Autowired поле = null ; Вылетает NPE

Также есть вопрос как для тестов сделать отдельный application.properties , чтоб для тестов использовать например базу данных в памяти , а не менять основную.

Comment: Странная ошибка, судя по коду все, вроде, должно работать. Можешь код на гитхаб выложить?

Comment: https://github.com/flagmen/trainsAPP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя там мульти-модульный проект. Сам контекст поднимается в одном модуле (console), а тесты находятся в другом. Чтобы они заработали им нужен какой-то стартовый конфигурационный класс, который поднимет контекст (как-то так...).
Поэтому делаем класс `TestConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan("dev5.lavishek.trains.entity")
public class TestConfig {
}
```

И рядом делаем тестовый класс:

```
@ActiveProfiles("h2")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class TicketRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired private TicketRepository repo;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        repo.save(asList(
                new Ticket(LocalDate.now(), 1, null, null, null, null, null),
                new Ticket(LocalDate.now(), 2, null, null, null, null, null))
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void findAllTest() throws Exception {
        assertThat(repo).isNotNull();
        assertThat(repo.findAll()).hasSize(2);
    }
}
```

`@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)` - эта аннотация говорит какой класс использовать для конфигурации контекста.

Далее, переименовываем твой `application.properties` в `application-nc.properties` (чтобы он не мешал) и создаем пустой файл `application-h2.properties` - это нужно, во-первых, чтобы сказать тесту, что мы хотим использовать профиль "h2" (см. подробнее [здесь](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)), а во-вторых, Спринг сам поднимает базу H2 в памяти, если она есть в зависимостях (поэтому файл пустой). (Можешь пропустить этот шаг, если у тебя все заработает без него.)

Чтобы все заработало, в `pom.xml` модуля `service` нужно удалить зависимость `org.springframework:spring-context` - она мешает подняться контексту.

---

Это что, тестовое от NC?..

Comment: Нет, это проект

Comment: Тогда проверь - как мне показалось в модулях много лишних зависимостей - hibernate, data-commons и т.п. Если не секрет, зачем слои разнес по модулям?

Comment: Попросили микросервисную архитектуру , по поводу зависимостей , спасибо проверю

Comment: После того как переименовал applaction.properties база данных в основном приложении слетела , я так понимаю , надо в Application , как то путь к properties прописать?

Comment: И как сделать инициализацию данных не в setUp а из sql скрипта?

Comment: Сделал всё как сказали , репозиторий все равно NULL !

Comment: @flagmen [сличай...](https://github.com/Cepr0/trainsAPP/commit/34bc79b94cbc74257fb0b499c2b4ea76a1f607db)

Comment: Все поправил , теперь spring загружается , но вылез новый exception Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Я так понял,что само spring boot application в другом пакете и он не знает , откуда его грузить, добавил в pom который в dao зависимость console и установил scope test , теперь maven говорит , что у меня циклическая зависимость модулей NC:dao:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> NC:console:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> NC:service:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> NC:dao:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ . Также в тестовом классе добавил @ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)

Comment: Закоммитил изменения на гитхабе, если не трудно можете пожалуйста посмотреть ?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать аннотацию @TestPropertySource, чтобы указать на файл с настройками. Можете создать тестовые настройки.

из javadoc:

> test property sources can be used to selectively override properties
>   defined in system and application property sources

test property sources может использоваться для выборочного переопределения свойств системы и приложения

Например:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExampleApplication.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class ExampleApplicationTests {

}
```

Comment: TestPropertySource я так понял , чтобы бд другую например подключить , а что за @SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = ExampleApplication.class) , и что должно быть в классе ExampleApplication

Comment: Это конфигурация spring через java класс, если у вас такой нет, то можете удалить аннотацию

Comment: Да , у меня такой нету , но Exception не пропал